# How can i edit my code to count and display how many times each name appears on my list

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, counter

Since this is for a beginners class we have not talked about many of the solutions i read here so i wanted to ask based on my code what can i do.

For each name in the file, (last name followed by a comma, followed by one or more spaces, followed by first name) displays the number of times that the names appears in the file. (i.e. name: count). This list of names must be displayed in the ascending order of the names. All first and last names must be capitalized. Each name must be displayed only once.

```
       ******* First Names count*********
       Adriana 4
       Colette 4
       Emmanuel 1
       Gerri 1
       Gretta 1
       Kirsten 2
       Marcia 2
       Neva 1
       Shawanda 1
```

This is what i have so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
    getNames(first, last);
    //display(first);
    //display(last);
    capitalize(first, last);
    //capitalize(last);
    ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
        allNames.add(last.get(i) + ", " + first.get(i));
    }
    ArrayList<String> capNames = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("***************All Names************");
    //System.out.println(allNames);
    //capitalize(allNames);
    display(allNames);

}

/**
* @param fn
* @param ln
*
* @throws java.io.IOException
*/

public static void getNames(ArrayList<String> fn,
                            ArrayList<String> ln) throws IOException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is the name input file? ");

    String fileName = kb.next();

    File inpFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = in.next();
        String lastName = in.next();
        fn.add(firstName);
        ln.add(lastName);
    }

}

public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> first,
                                ArrayList<String> last) {

    for (int i=0; i<first.size(); i++) {
        String capFirst = first.get(i).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() 
                        + first.get(i).substring(1).toLowerCase();
        first.set(i, capFirst);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<last.size(); i++) {
        String capLast = last.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                        last.get(i).substring(1).toLowerCase();
        last.set(i, capLast);
    }
}     

public static void display(ArrayList<String> allNames) {

    for (int i = 0; i < allNames.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(allNames.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: input is: name space lastname

Comment: My personal advice for a beginner: 1. Learn to indent well.  It is a mess now.  2. Don't hesitate when you need to type a few more characters for a more descriptive name.  `fn`, `kb`, `inpFile` etc can be named better.  However as a beginner you are doing well in following naming convention :)

Comment: And, most important is, what is the problem you are facing?  Simply throwing out some incomplete code and the homework question, and ask for the solution is not the way Stackoverflow works.  Be specific on what your problem.  You have no idea on how to count?  You have problem reading from input? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my comments in the code. I'd modify your code into doing something like this :)

In your code, the method to read the file is incorrect, because first and last names are on the same line separated by a comma. Therefore we need to read this line and split first and last names into seperate strings. However your later comments state that there is no comma, in that case you'll need to modify getNames() method to cater for this.

I've used a HashMap to store first names and their number of appearances.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    private ArrayList<String[]> allNames;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Test t = new Test();
        t.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        try {
            this.getNames();
            this.printAll();
            this.printFirstNamesCount();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx) {

            System.out.println("Input file error. Info : " + ioEx.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void getNames() throws IOException {

        allNames = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the name input file? ");
        String fileName = kb.next();
        File inpFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

        while (in.hasNext()) {

            //slot the string into a arry (last name, first name)
            //use nextLine() or it won't read beyond spaces
            String[] tmp = in.nextLine().split(",");
            //remove white spaces in the first name
            tmp[1] = tmp[1].replaceAll("\\s+","");
            //capitalize both first and last names
            tmp[0] = capitalize(tmp[0]);
            tmp[1] = capitalize(tmp[1]);
            allNames.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    private void printAll() {

        System.out.println("******* All Names *********");

        for(String[] tmp : allNames) {

            //array index 1 is they first name and 0 is the last name
            System.out.println(tmp[1] + " " + tmp[0]);
        }
    }

    private void printFirstNamesCount() {

        HashMap<String, Integer> firstNamesCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(String[] tmp : allNames) {

            //we haven't counted this first name yet
            if(firstNamesCount.get(tmp[1]) == null) {

                firstNamesCount.put(tmp[1], 1);
            }
            //we have counted this name, so let's just increment it
            else {

                firstNamesCount.put(tmp[1], (firstNamesCount.get(tmp[1]) + 1));
            }
        }

        //now let's print the hash map

        System.out.println("******* First Names Count *********");

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : firstNamesCount.entrySet()) {

            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue());
        }
    }

    //capitalize the first letter
    private String capitalize(String line) {

        return Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
    }
}
```

And my input file looked like this,

```
Gunasekara, Achintha
Gun,  Achintha
Simpson, Homer
Simpson, Bart
Singclar, James
Silver, Paul
Sil, Paul,
Si,   Paul,
Kang, David
```

And you should get an output that looks like,

```
Archies-MacBook-Pro:Downloads archieg$ java Test 
What is the name input file? test.txt
******* All Names *********
Achintha Gunasekara
Achintha Gun
Homer Simpson
Bart Simpson
James Singclar
Paul Silver
Paul Sil
Paul Si
David Kang
******* First Names Count *********
James - 1
David - 1
Homer - 1
Achintha - 2
Paul - 3
Bart - 1
Archies-MacBook-Pro:Downloads archieg$
```

Comment: thanks, this part gives me an error:     Test t = new Test();
        t.go();
    }

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Test is the class name I've used. Make sure to match this to your class name and file name

Comment: it tells me i have to create the class test and then the method go

Comment: Test is the class name I've used. Make sure to match this to your class name and file name. What is your class called?

Comment: imho it is meaningless to move the original code in `main()` to instance method `go()` and makes the `main()` calling `go()`.  You haven't make `Test` a meaningful class in such aspect.  And such change only distract people from your actual solution

Comment: yes you are correct, i did not realize it was the name

Comment: run:
What is the name input file? input.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at tres.Tres.getNames(Tres.java:62)
 at tres.Tres.go(Tres.java:37)
 at tres.Tres.main(Tres.java:31)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: @Adrian Shum, I agree, all that could just go into main method :)

Comment: @maria andrea erramouspe, please compare my code to yours, I did find a bug before and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

i modified your code slightly 
i added static class  NameInf to carry the information of name "the first name and its count so far "

and added method firstNameCounts that search the first arraylist to find the count of repeated names ^-^

```
static class NameInf {

    String name;
    int count = 0;

    public NameInf(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    //overide default equal method so two object are equal if with same
    //name even they are not have same refence
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof NameInf) {
            NameInf casted = (NameInf) obj;
            return casted.name.equals(this.name);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
    getNames(first, last);
    //display(first);
    //display(last);
    capitalize(first, last);
    //capitalize(last);
    ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
        allNames.add(last.get(i) + ", " + first.get(i));
    }
    //ArrayList<String> capNames = new ArrayList<>(); // used for what? 

    System.out.println("***************All Names************");
    //System.out.println(allNames);
    //capitalize(allNames);
    display(allNames);

    ArrayList<NameInf> fnc= firstNamesCount(first);
    for(NameInf ni : fnc){
        System.out.println(ni.name + " " + ni.count);
    }
}

/**
 * @param fn
 * @param ln
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void getNames(ArrayList<String> fn,
        ArrayList<String> ln) throws IOException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is the name input file? ");

    String fileName = kb.next();

    File inpFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = in.next();
        String lastName = in.next();
        fn.add(firstName);
        ln.add(lastName);
    }

}

public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> first,
        ArrayList<String> last) {

    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
        String capFirst = first.get(i).substring(0, 1)
                .toUpperCase() + first.get(i).substring(1).toLowerCase();
        first.set(i, capFirst);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < last.size(); i++) {
        String capLast = last.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + last.get(i).substring(1).toLowerCase();
        last.set(i, capLast);
    }
}

public static void display(ArrayList<String> allNames) {

    for (int i = 0; i < allNames.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(allNames.get(i));

    }
}

public static ArrayList<NameInf> firstNamesCount(ArrayList<String> firstNames) {
    ArrayList<NameInf> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String n : firstNames) {
        NameInf nameinf = new NameInf(n);
        int index = temp.indexOf(nameinf) ;
        if (index == -1) {
            nameinf.count = 1 ;
            temp.add(nameinf);
        }else{
            temp.get(index).count++;
        }
    }
    return temp ;
}
```

Comment: omg it worked, you guys are great i have been working on this for days, since im new there are a lot of things that are not common sense in java for me and i get confused, but thankssssss

Comment: if i want to do the same for lastnames, do i modify the names nameInf and ni?

Comment: you can add this 
    `ArrayList<NameInf> lnc = firstNamesCount(last);
    for(NameInf ni : lnc){
        System.out.println(ni.name + " " + ni.count);
    }` also change the method firstNamesCount to namesCount to make it more meaningfull or what you whant